# Should I use "<table mat table ... " or "<mat-table ..."

Tags: angular, tags, mat-table

The title already says it, which one should I use and is there / what is the difference between having

```
<table mat table [dataSource]="items" ...
```

or

```
<mat table [dataSource]="items" ...
```

in my HTML markup?

On a cursory glance they both work fine, but I assume there must be a difference...

**EDIT:**
I'm specifically talking about resizeable columns, like in this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtfc5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you switch the

Comment: they are the same, but in angular material docs tell you to put `<table mat-table [dataSource]=”myDataArray”>`. So I will put it like that.

Comment: here you have the docs: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: ```<mat-table>``` uses display flex. 

Look at the first two example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

In my case, for something like text aligning, it was much easier to go with ```<mat-table>```

Comment: The docs indicate that both approaches are recommended, but they put this caveat in for the flex version: "Note that this approach means you cannot include certain native-table features such colspan/rowspan or have columns that resize themselves based on their content."  Seems like maybe the answer is go with the default table setup until you encounter a limitation-
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#tables-with-code-display-flex-code-

Answer (score 20):

**Option 1** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prq2ju): `<mat-table>`: When you use as an element it uses CSS flex-box properties to align your data/table so **when you have very long text it will not resize automatically** unless specified otherwise. 
Note: using this option you have to **compromise** on `rowspan` and `colspan` such as if the need arises you can't span your rows/cols

**Option 2** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxpwet): `table[mat-table]`: When you use as an attribute to html table the td **takes care of auto resizing** its content based on the cell in turn based to the column. So the whole column gets the width

The modern approach would be to use the **Option-1 CSS flex-box approach**, but if you have very long content in cell you can specify the column width to a large number, but if you don't want to go to a lot of hassle you can use it with **Option-2 native html `table/tr/td`**

Here is the [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/c05a07ed9cf9ecb7272fb674da3fa190a1f6a5f8/src/material/table/table.ts#L16) code of Angular material table

Happy Coding!